# Testing injected controllers in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Overriding-bindings-in-a-functional-test) in Play's documentation to test a Controller with an injected object. I replicated the example, but I'm getting an error when trying to invoke the web page:

> No implementation for test.Component was bound.

The error seems right as I'm not invoking the `binding` method, but how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
package test

import play.api.mvc._
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.{ Environment, Configuration }
import play.api.inject.Module

trait Component {
  def hello: String
}

class DefaultComponent extends Component {
  def hello = "default"
}

class MockComponent extends Component {
  def hello = "mock"
}


class ComponentModule extends Module {
  def bindings(env: Environment, conf: Configuration) = Seq(
    bind[Component].to[DefaultComponent]
  )
}

class Application @Inject() (component: Component) extends Controller {
  def index() = Action {
    Ok(component.hello)
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you running this code? How are you making sure the `ComponentModule` is being recognized by play?

Comment: I have an entry in routes `GET /testapp test.Application.index`. I don't know how to make `ComponentModule` recognized by Play, that's the part missing in Play's example, see the link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to application.conf

```
play {
    modules {
        enabled += test.ComponentModule 
    }
}
```